# Excel, deleting nth of row's every 60th

Tags: excel, vba

I have huge excel data performance for sensors. The data include time series! and its record every 5 second. In general, i have `17281 rows` of data which is a record for only one day.
i need to visualize the data but its too sharp with every 5 second record, so i want to scale the time series to from every 5 second to every 5 minutes!

I tried to do that by deleting the extra rows...

every `5 minutes = 60 "5 second"`

so i need to delete `60 row` and keep the `61th`, then delete the next 60 and keep the 121th and so on...

i tried to use VB code method but i couldn't do it!!!

Please anyone can help :(

Here's my recorded macro, when i tried to do the first few rows... i hope it can give some clear image of the problem...

---

```
Sub MacroDeleteTest1()
'
' MacroDeleteTest1 Macro
'

'
    Rows("2:2").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=31
    Rows("2:60").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("3:3").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=34
    Rows("3:61").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("4:4").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=33
    Rows("4:62").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("5:5").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=35
    Rows("5:63").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("6:6").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=34
    Rows("6:64").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("7:7").Select
End Sub
```

---

Thank you...

Comment: You could extract the relevant data by looping over the rows using FOR ... NEXT with the optional "STEP" set to 60...

Comment: I tried with that, but i always get wrong time sequence after few hundreds rows..

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Do you get the right results with the solution provided by Vinny Roe?

Comment: YES, But you need to change from 60 to 59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. Set range rStart to be the first cell of your data to begin with.

```
Sub delete60()

Dim rStart As Range
Const cCOLF As Long = 5    ' Offset across of column F

    Set rStart = Sheet1.Range("A1")

    Do While rStart.Offset(1, 0).Value <> ""
        With Range(rStart.Offset(1, cCOLF), rStart.Offset(59, cCOLF))
            rStart.Offset(0, cCOLF).Value = Evaluate("SUM(" & .Address & ")")
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        Set rStart = rStart.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Again, Can you help with some changes in that code!! Before i delete the rows, i need to have the SUM of the range and make it as a value of the remaining row! so it will be have sum of every 59 row and   make it in 60th row and delete the range "raptly". by the way i need to make the SUM process for only one Column, which is "F". Can you help Pleaaaaase :)

Comment: Edited to include request to sum values. NB I changed "Offset(60,.." to "Offset(59,..." which I think is correct.